# How can I widen brakes on an '09 Specialized Transition Pro?

Tags: brakes

I just picked up an '09 Transition on craigslist, and was expectantly dismayed to find that the stock brakes aren't quite wide enough for my Zipp 404 firecrests.  When I remove the straddle cable (unsure if that's correct term for this particular type of brakes), they open up enough for the super wide 404s.

Does anybody either a)  know the part number for the straddle "cable" that came stock, so I can order a slightly longer one or b) have any suggestions for how I can open the brakes up another 4mm?

[image]

Reference image:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt9f0.jpg.  What I'm calling the "straddle cable" is what connects the two calipers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part is specific to Specialized. They only make one size. If you loosen the center cable, it should have more than enough clearance for a Zipp wheel, even if you have the new Firecrest design.

The straddle clip can be replaced with a standard cantilever straddle cable and a hook, like this:

[image: Examle of cantilever with straddle cable]

but it is not ideal for leverage on the brakes, which may reduce your stopping power. And I'm not suggesting installing the cantilever brake, only using the bridge and straddle cable.

Comment: Of course.  I'm a bit dumbfounded I didn't put 2 and 2 together to realize loosening that center cable would suffice.   Thanks!

Comment: ...and do make sure the cable is not frayed at the point it was bolted up to before.